# start of dhcp failed on centos

Tags: centos, dhcp, startup, failed

i try to config DHCP on centos. when i start service by `#service dhcpd restart` it failed.

the result of `#tail -f /var/log/messages` :

```
Dec 31 19:26:31 localhost dhcpd: exiting.
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Dec 31 19:27:04 localhost dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
```

and the result of `dhcpd -t`

```
 Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
 Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
 All rights reserved.
 For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
 Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
```

please help me.

Comment: Have you read our FAQ? it states this site is for professional sysadmins, give that a think.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those error messages is useful. The useful information is provided in `/var/log/messages` immediately before the portion that you quote.

Use your favourite text editor/pager to have a look at the full transcript provided by dhcpd. Please read it carefully, it will contain useful information for you to act upon.